# mongodump command resulting in panic: send on closed channel goroutine 52 [running]:

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'm looking for ideas on how to resolve a panic I'm seeing while running the `mongodump` command.   Details are

mongodb:  `version 4.2.11` a replica set configuration.

mongodump:

```
mongodump version: r4.2.24
git version: 5e4ec1d24431fcdd28b579a024c5c801b8cde4e2
Go version: go1.12.17
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
```

Stack Trace:

```
goroutine 19 [running]:
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/archive.(*MuxIn).Open(0xc000112500)
    github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/vendor/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/archive/multiplexer.go:282 +0x22c
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump.(*MongoDump).dumpValidatedQueryToIntent(0xc0000d8370, 0x11?, 0xc00011c3f0, {0x0?, 0x0}, 0xc00011b430?)
    github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump/mongodump.go:636 +0x98
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump.(*MongoDump).dumpQueryToIntent(...)
    github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump/mongodump.go:607
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump.(*MongoDump).DumpIntent(0xc0000d8370, 0xc00011c3f0, {0x0, 0x0})
    github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump/mongodump.go:590 +0x647
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump.(*MongoDump).DumpIntents.func1(0x0?)
    github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump/mongodump.go:502 +0xfe
created by github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump.(*MongoDump).DumpIntents
    github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongodump/mongodump.go:491 +0x4d9
```

The mongodump command:

```
mongodump --quiet  --dumpDbUsersAndRoles --authenticationDatabase=admin   --authenticationMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256 --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --host <HOST> --db sample-database --archive | aws s3 cp - s3://samplbucket/samplefld
```

The failure will happens in 1 out every 6 databases I am exporting but not does not die consistently on any particular database.   Looking over the server side configuration for mongodb I don't see any that would interfere with an active connection.

Current plan is to upgrade to the latest version of mongodb ( or perhaps DocumentDb) but if anyone has any ideas or thoughts to share until then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and found that it was caused by my machine not having enough free RAM. It seems that over time, a NodeJS container had grown to consume 3.5/4.0 G of RAM on the VM. A reboot cleared things up enough to allow for `mongodump` to run, but I also upgraded the RAM on the machine